# Symfony EntityType required empty option

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to create a dropdown list (EntityType) with the **selection required** but allow an option which maps to null.

In other words there is a list of entities in a drop down list and an additional option that maps to null and the user has to click on the list to select one.

I can try the following code, but the problem is that the user is not required to click on the drop down to select the option that maps to null labelled 'Other':

```
$choices = $em->getRepository(Instrument::class)->findAll();
$choices[] = ['Other' => null];

$form->add('instrument', EntityType::class, [
    'placeholder' => 'Other',
    'class' => Instrument::class,
    'required' => true,
    'choices' => $choices,
]);
```

Is there anyway to set the selection required with an option that maps to null?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the 'required' option to true and still allow for a null option in the dropdown. You can use a placeholder to display the text for the null option and add a validation constraint to check if the selected value is not null.

Example:

```
$choices = $em->getRepository(Instrument::class)->findAll();
$choices[] = ['Other' => null];

$form->add('instrument', EntityType::class, [
    'placeholder' => 'Please select an option or Other',
    'class' => Instrument::class,
    'required' => true,
    'choices' => $choices,
    'constraints' => [
        new NotNull([
            'message' => 'Please select an option or Other'
        ])
    ],
]);
```

Comment: The selection is still not obligatory when I test with this code. If I remove the 'Other' => null line the selection becomes obligatory but there is no null option